# Asynchronous socket send on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, asynchronous, send

When send on an asynchronous socket returns EAGAIN, does that mean :
that the current call has just been successfully queued or that nothing was done because the system is still processing a previous send ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `man 2 send`:

> The socket is marked nonblocking and the requested operation would block. POSIX.1-2001 allows either error to be returned for this case, and does not require this constants [EAGAIN EWOULDBLOCK] to have the same value, so a portable application should check for both possibilities.

So, I think `EAGAIN` means: `be careful, the message did not fit into send buffer, this call would be blocked in normal (blocking) mode. Use select(2) to determine whether you can send more data.`

P.S. Actually, looks like the call failed and nothing was done.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing was done.

If something is done, the return value tells you how many characters were sent. As you get the return value -1 and errno=EAGAIN, nothing was sent.